# 'Welcome' message from Nginx shown when I run my wsgi Django project + Nginx + Gunicorn

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

I'm beginner in Django and I've finished my first project.
I have an Ubuntu server in Digital Ocean and this is what I've done:

My project nginx configuration file:

```
server {
server_name domain.com;

access_log off;

location /static/ {
    alias /opt/myenv/static/;
}

location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
}
```

My project is located in `/opt/myenv/myenv/`

When I execute `gunicorn myproject.wsgi` it looks like it's running

```
Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (1481)
```

But when I access into my IP, I just see an Welcome message from Nginx.
What is happening?
(Sorry my bad english)

Comment: Have you done a reload or restart of nginx since you made the changes to the config? Is the config in the correct location? what does nginx -T show you?

Comment: Yes, I already restarted nginx. nginx -T says it's ok.

Comment: `nginx -T` should show you the full configuration. `nginx -t` shows if your configuration is valid.

Comment: My bad. nginx -t says configurations are valid.

Comment: Great now does nginx -T show you the above server block as you would expect? If not it points to nginx not seeing your changes.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment (rep points) so will post here.

1. You have Gunicorn bound to :8000 but have Nginx looking at :8001
2. Did you put this config in sites-available and symlink to sites-enabled, then remove "default" from sites-enabled? (If it's showing welcome I assume not)
3. I don't see where you are directing Nginx to listen:

   ```
   server {
           listen 80 default_server;
           listen [::]:80;
           ...
   ```

Any reason you are not setting up Gunicorn using a unix sock instead and configuring Nginx to that?  Here's a typical config for this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name server_domain_or_IP;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/user/myproject;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/user/myproject/myproject.sock;
    }
}
```